# Should I say ON a circuit or IN a circuit?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Consider these two phrases:

1. I would like to know the current ____ a circuit.
2. The resistor ___ the circuit.

Should I use ON or IN and why?

I know that ON is for surfaces and IN is for inside something.

In the first example you do not see the current, because it circulates inside the components, so I would be inclined to use IN.

In the second case, the resistor is visible and is on a surface. I would be inclined to use ON.

Is that correct?

Comment: I'm sure that someone can come up with contexts where "on" is more appropriate, but for about 95% of cases you'd say "in", or choose something else entirely.  (The resistor is a part of the circuit and therefore "in" the circuit.)

Comment: thanks and what about the first case... current is circulating INSIDE...

Comment: "In" or "through", depending on the phase of the moon.

Comment: thanks again. Can you convert this comment INTO an answer? :)

Comment: Isn't it more natural to say *the current* **of** *a circuit*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
1   I would like to know the current on a circuit.
2   The resistor in  the circuit.
```

If you specify running current , then :...know the current running through the circuit

Comment: Perhaps also: the current around the circuit.

Comment: @GEdgar - if the current is around the circuit (taking "circuit" in the electronics sense) then the circuit is irrelevant.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You *cannot* say "the current *on* a circuit."

Answer (score 1):

In my experience as a student of physics and a long-time electronics hobbyist:

It is incorrect to say, "the current on a circuit." At least in AmE, you *must* say "the current *in* a circuit." (You could also say, "the current *through* a circuit.")

You could say, "the resistor on a circuit*board*," or, "the resistor in a circuit," but never have I heard, "the resistor on a circuit."

[For a reference, you might want to look at Google Ngram Viewer's data.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+circuit%2Con+a+circuit%2Cthrough+a+circuit%2Cof+a+circuit%2Cinside+a+circuit%2Caround+a+circuit&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20circuit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20circuit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrough%20a%20circuit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20a%20circuit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinside%20a%20circuit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caround%20a%20circuit%3B%2Cc0)